# How to do Authentication with UPS through API?

Tags: api, authentication, ups

I am in the process of integrating UPS with our application.

But I got stuck with Authentication. How do I need to connect with UPS?
What is the endpoint for UPS Authorization? I have researched it and haven't found any proper documentation.

Please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. Have you seen the docu here, https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US

Comment: Yes, but for UPS there is no dedicated endpoint to do the authentication.